# Display a file after it has been written in Matlab?

Tags: macos, file, matlab

Is it possible to display a .txt file that has been just created by Matlab ? Basically make it pop up and become an active window (**not in matlab, but open the text file as if you are opening it from a folder**). If so, what is the code to accomplish that ? Using a MAC OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `system('notepad filename.txt')` on Windows and `system('open filename.txt')` on Mac. When you use `open`, the OS will automatically use whatever application you have set as default for that file type. If you want to open it in a specific editor that is different from the default, replace `open` with the correct command (if on the path) or use the `-a` flag to `open` as:

```
system('open -a /full/path/to/application filename.txt')
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is on Mac, my bad.

Comment: @LoremIpsum as mentioned in the question, I want it to open as a new active window, not in matlab.

Comment: @NLed I meant `system('open filename.txt')`. Ben's answer is an example and you obviously have to substitute the correct command for your OS i.e. replace notepad/textedit with whatever you use — textmate/vim/emacs/pico/nano/blah... If you use `open` as I mentioned, it'll use whatever is specified for that file type.

Comment: @LoremIpsum Can you add that as an answer to mark it correct ?

Comment: @NLed You can just accept Ben's instead. I've added it to his answer.

Comment: FYI, the Windows equivalent to `open`, which looks up the associated application, is `cmd /E:ON /C start document.ext`.  @Lorem, when specifying the application path, what's the advantage of `open`?

Comment: @BenVoigt The advantage is that it can be any application, and not necessarily one that can understand command line arguments. `open` figures out how to call the file in the application natively. For example, you could do `open -a /path/to/Safari.app file.html` to open it in Safari, whereas `/path/to/Safari.app file.html` is not permitted (and doesn't make sense, because that is actually a directory on OS X, not a file).

Comment: @LoremIpsum: Oh ok, so among other abilities, you can pass an application identifier which isn't actually the main executable.  That's useful.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In fact, one could even simply do `open -a AppName file`  to open it (instead of the full path) and it searches in the default location of `/Application`. In short, it's a command line equivalent for double clicking a file or right-click > open with application.